# How to stop long javascript loops from crashing the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button in my page that's looping a series of DIVs and editing them (appending text mostly, nothing serious),
The thing is, the number of DIVs is changing by the user (The user can add or remove them freely),

I'm looping the DIVs via jQuery $.each function:

```
var DomToEdit = $('.divs_to_edit');
$.each(DomToEdit, function() { $(this).append('text'); ... });
```

the variable DomToEdit contains somewhat unlimited number of divs, and then I refer to them via the $.each function.

Sometimes while doing the $.each loop the user gets to wait for a couple of secons, and in worse cases the browser is crashing

Is there a way to prevent this? Maybe having the loop "sleep" after 50 DIVs?

Thanks

EDIT: I didn't use the same ID, sorry - it was a flaw in my explanation. I use the same class. :)

Comment: I hope you don't have divs with the same IDs.

Comment: It seems strange that you have multiple elements with the same ID, you should put a class instead of divs_to_edit then use $('.divs_to_edit'); this may improve performance

Comment: Should probably look at improving your markup first, if there are a lot of elements.

Comment: Wouldn't `DomToEdit.each(function(){})` be better?

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of the function in the `.each` handler is the index of the current element. you can simply add a check before it, and `return false` to stop the loop.

```
$.each(DomToEdit, function(i) { // or DomToEdit.each(function() {
    if (i === 50) return false;
    ..
```

`DomToEdit` is a jQuery object, so [`$.each(DomToEdit, fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [`DomToEdit.each(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) are equivalent.

A more effective method is to cut off the elements, using [`.slice(0, 50)`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

```
DomToEdit.slice(0, 50).each( function(i) {
    ..
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a timer which will execute append 50 div's every 5 seconds and works thru the array of div until it finishes iterating all div.

Below code works on 50 div every 5 seconds.

```
var DomToEdit = $('#divs_to_edit');
var timer = setInterval( function () { //<-- Create a Timer
   $.each(DomToEdit, function(index) { //<-- Iterate thru divs
       if (index == 50) return;        //<-- Return on 50 for later
       $(this).append('text'); 
   });
   DomToEdit = DomToEdit.slice(0, 50); //<-- Slice the processed div's

   // Clear timer when all elements are processed.
   if (DomToEdit.length == 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
   }
}, 5000);                              // <-- Do the steps on every 5 secs
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I think that code can potentially cause a crash, I'll create a self-decementing `breaker` variable that breaks out of a loop after a certain number of loop cycles.

```
var breaker = 100;
while(true) {
    breaker--;if(breaker<0){console.log("Oh snap batman");break;}


    console.log("CRASH");

}
```

The method could execute alternative code that works around the crash as well. Usually, I just try to fix the code somehow ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could `setTimeout` to 0 in order to queue the processing of each element into the execution stack (0 makes it just queue without delay):

```
$.each(DomToEdit, function() { 
    var elem = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() { elem.append('text'); }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could queue the tasks and then execute tasks
in batches of X every Y milliseconds:

```
var queue = [];

$.each(DomToEdit, function () {
    queue.push( $.proxy( function () {
        $(this).append('text');
    }, this ));
});

window.setInterval( function(){
    var l = 100;

    while( queue.length && l-- ) { //Keep executing tasks until there
                                   //is no more or maximum amount of tasks
                                   //executed for this batch is executed
        queue.shift()();
    }

}, 50 );
```

The real fix is of course carefully review what you are doing and fix that. `$('#divs_to_edit')` always returns a single element max so `.each` doesn't make much sense here for example...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with an extremely large number of elements, that it would actually be less processor intensive to pull the entire container element as a string and run a Javascript `.replace()` on it and replace the entire container, than looping through hundreds of thousands of elements?